# How can I determine if expression passed as parameter to where extension method will be evaluated on the server

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I determine if expression, passed to `where()` method as a parameter, will be converted to query? Why for example this expression when passed as a parameter  fails to be converted to query

**Failed expression:**

```cs
m => (m => (m => (m.Foo!= null) &&
   m.Foo.ToUpper().Contains(_foo.ToUpper())).Invoke(m) && (m
   => (m.Bar != null) && m.Bar.ToUpper().Contains(_bar.ToUpper())).Invoke(m)).Invoke(m)
   && (m => (m.Baz != null) &&
   m.Baz.ToUpper().Contains(_baz.ToUpper())).Invoke(m)
```

and this one is successfully converted to query:

**Successful expression:**

```cs
m => (m => (m.Foo!= null) &&
   m.Foo.ToUpper().Contains(_foo.ToUpper())).Invoke(m) && (m
   => (m.Bar!= null) && m.Bar.ToUpper().Contains(_bar.ToUpper())).Invoke(m)
```

Comment: If you use EF Core 3.1, you'll get an exception if you try to use a query that can't get translated to SQL. With EF Core 2.1 you get a runtime warning. And *NONE* of those expressions can be translated to SQL due to `Invoke()`. I suspect what you posted is partial code from an attempt to generate some kind of dynamic SQL? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Most of those expressions can be eliminated. String matching in SQL depends on the column's collation, which quite often is case-*in*sensitive. You could just write `where m.Foo.Contais(something)`. There's no need to check for null either, SQL doesn't throw NREs. If a column is null, `LIKE '%abc%'` fails. All those queries could be rewritten as `where m.Foo.Contains(_foo) && m.Bar.Contains(_bar)`

Comment: In fact, those `ToUpper()` calls *prevent* the server from using any indexes. Indexes are built using a table's actual data while `ToUpper()` changes that data to something else. The server has to scan the entire table to perform that conversion and find matching rows. On the other hand, `Contains` is already scanning everything - the `LIKE '%abc%` expression it generates can't take advantage of indexing. If it was `StartsWith` the expression would be `LIKE 'abc%'` which is treated as a range query by the server and takes advantage of indexing

Comment: Yeah Invoke was my suspect too but, second expression was realy converting to query, i checked with SQL server profiler so I was realy confused, I since changed implementation to eliminate ```Invoke()``` altogether, but this still bugs me.

Comment: I'm aware that ```ToUpper()``` wont be most optimized thing ever but it seems to me like the cleanest way to accomplish case insensitivity. I guess there are more optimal ways but this one is very concise and easy to read

Comment: You posted just part of an expression, it's impossible to say what's wrong or what is going on. Why write such code in the first place?

Comment: `it seems to me like the cleanest way to accomplish case insensitivity.` Quite the opposite, it's the worst way possible. It's not just performance, this is simply **wrong**. Collations include case conversion rules. Look for the Turkish I or the Danish aa. If you use SQL Server it's also meaningless, it only helps to kill performance and lock entire tables. There's nothing cleaner or easier to understand than a simple `m.Foo== _foo`

Comment: Well this was an attempt to write dynamic expression builder that would be used for searching, obviously it was wildly unssuccessfull. And to the point of ```ToUpper()``` being the worst possible way to implement case insensitivity I was thinking more in terms of code readability, thank you for pointing out that performances are abysmal.

Comment: Thank you for guidelines regarding collations i will look into it